# Sorting the 10 highest projects alphabetically with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following statement that returns the 10 highest projects.

```
Timesheet.joins(:project).select('projects.name as name, SUM(value) AS Minutes').group('projects.name').order('Minutes DESC').limit(10)
```

How can I order them alphabetically?  I tried putting .order('name') behind the statement but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried ending this with "sort_by(&:name)"? It won't sort in the Query but rather by using ruby Enumerable#sort_by. (Sorry no back ticks on my phone's keyboard)

Comment: Try: `Timesheet.joins(:project).select('projects.name as project_name, SUM(value) AS minutes').group('projects.name').order(:project_name => :asc, :minutes => :desc).limit(10)`

Comment: @engineersmnky great, that works, if you add it as answer I'll mark it as such.
Surya that doesn't work because then it will generate a query that will not take the 10 highest projects by value but instead just the first 10 alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Enumerable#sort_by` method like so

```
 Timesheet.joins(:project).
   select('projects.name as name, SUM(value) AS Minutes').
   group('projects.name').
   order('Minutes DESC').
   limit(10).
   sort_by(&:name)
```

This will run your original query and then use `sort_by` to add the additional level of sorting requested.